# Android Video view ceating black window while make it gone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

My application has several pages of book. In some of page I am playing video using video view. I am checking if I have any video for that page. If yes, than I am making videoview visible and passing Uri. If not, I am making it gone.

Now the problem is, once i reached to that screen and then if I swipe left/right it's creating black window in every subsequent screen. Why?

Comment: It will be more clear if you upload the chunk of code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. When you want to show video make videoView.setZOrderOnTop(false); and when you want to hide video view jusr make videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

Comment: Warning! if set setZOrderOnTop, it becomes top view over ActionBar